# sql and linq query

Tags: sql, linq, linq-to-sql

Database has tables Photos and PhotoAlbums. I need a query that will select all albums and only one photo from each album. I need SQL and LINQ version of this query. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which photo from each album do you want?

Comment: for now any photo.. later I will edit table Photos so that it has field "albumcover", but now I need random one

Comment: your selected query is inefficient, as it must run a different query to find the photo for each row returned from PhotoAlbums. You would be much better off using a derived table and joining PhotoAlbums to that.

Comment: I may agree with KM sub-queries are not recommended in the application because it reduces performance while fetching the data. in this scenario the better way is to create a new column in "PhotoAlbums" Table named "DefaultPhoto" and put the default photo  id in it, which will make a straight forward select query with out any join which will enhance the performance and maintainability.

Comment: I agree with you, that is definitively less painful solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Linq I'm not that experienced in it so I'll only give the SQL Server Query

```
SELECT a.*,b.MyPhoto FROM PhotoAlbums a,(SELECT Top 1 myPhoto from Photos Where AlbumID = a.ID) b
```

Or This

```
SELECT a.AlbumID, a.Title, a.Date, (SELECT TOP (1) c.PhotoID FROM Photos c WHERE(c.AlbumID = a.AlbumID)) AS PhotoID FROM PhotoAlbums as a
```

Answer (score 1):

if the tables are like:

```
PhotoAlbums
AlbumID    PK
...

Photos
PhotoID    PK
AlbumID    FK
Photo
...
```

Here is the SQL query:

```
SELECT
    a.*,p.Photo 
    FROM PhotoAlbums a
        LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT
                             AlbumID,MIN(PhotoID) AS MinPhotoID
                             FROM Photos
                             GROUP BY AlbumID
                        ) dt ON a.AlbumID=dt.AlbumID
        LEFT OUTER JOIN Photos p ON dt.MinPhotoID=p.PhotoID
```

working example:

```
DECLARE @PhotoAlbums table (AlbumID  int)
INSERT @PhotoAlbums VALUES (1)
INSERT @PhotoAlbums VALUES (2)
INSERT @PhotoAlbums VALUES (3)

DECLARE @Photos table (PhotoID int,AlbumID int, Photo varchar(10))
INSERT @Photos VALUES (1,1,'A')
INSERT @Photos VALUES (2,1,'B')
INSERT @Photos VALUES (3,1,'C')
INSERT @Photos VALUES (4,2,'AA')
INSERT @Photos VALUES (5,3,'AAA')
INSERT @Photos VALUES (6,3,'BBB')

SELECT
    a.*,p.Photo 
    FROM @PhotoAlbums a
        LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT
                             AlbumID,MIN(PhotoID) AS MinPhotoID
                             FROM @Photos
                             GROUP BY AlbumID
                        ) dt ON a.AlbumID=dt.AlbumID
        LEFT OUTER JOIN @Photos p ON dt.MinPhotoID=p.PhotoID
```

OUTPUT:

```
AlbumID     Photo
----------- ----------
1           A
2           AA
3           AAA

(3 row(s) affected)
```

Comment: hmmm... When I try to execute your and Kronass's query, VS2008 formats the query and then returns error. Is SQL the same for MySQL and MSSQL?

Comment: And yes, the tables are like you assumed

Comment: If I click Execute, error is following: "Error in GROUP BY clause.
Unable to parse query text." If I click Verify Syntax, error is: "Incorrect syntax near 'a' "

Comment: See latest edit, I missed the `ON` here:  `) dt ON a.AlbumID=`, I also added a working example.

Comment: It's working now, thanks a lot. It's a bit complex to understand for me... What does 'dt' stand for? I suppose it stands for Photos table but I'm used to make alias of expression with 'AS'.

Comment: You wouldn't know LINQ version of this query?

Comment: the `LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT ...) dt` is a derived table, also known as an inline view.  It is a query that gets joined into the main query just like it was its own table.  I use it to get 1 photo per album.  I then need to join back to the Photos table using this Min =PhotoId to get the other columns form the Photos table.  I've never used LINQ, so I can't help there.

Answer (score 1):

The Linq query could be something like this:

```
from album in context.PhotoAlbums
from photo in album.Photos.Take(1).DefaultIfEmpty()
select new
   {
        Album = album,
        Photo = photo
   }
```